# Can't log into my email using Nexus 7 email client

Tags: email, nexus-7

I want to use the email app on my Nexus 7 to access my university email. These email accounts are provided by Microsoft.

After I enter my account name, on the second screen, it asks me about Account Type. POP3, IMAP or Exchange.

I tried

- with POP3 > enter password > Incoming server settings(used defaults) > When trying to sign in "Couldn't finish : Couldn't open connection to server."
- with IMAP, it asks for "sign in with password" or "sign in with google". In both cases, I get the error "Couldn't finish : Couldn't open connection to server"
- with Exchange I get the same error. But in this case the email server asks for a "client certificate", I haven't selected anything for that option.

What are the options (POP3, IMAP, Exchange) and how to setup this email client for my university account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get this information from your university. Ask the IT department to walk you through it or just give you the necessary information.
From what you've said:

> email accounts are provided by Microsoft.

seems to me they're using Exchange in a Windows domain (I could be wrong). Therefore, you'll need a server link, domain name, username, and password.

Also, on a separate note, you should do some research on how email works and email protocols (POP3, IMAP, SMTP, Exchange, Gmail, and so on). Here's a helpful link: [Email protocols: POP, IMAP and MAPI](http://it.med.miami.edu/x1111.xml)

Comment: Yes, what I needed was server link, security type and port number for IMAP and SMTP and I unchecked "signin" requirement.